# Append List of array to an array and repeat this in kotlin

Tags: arrays, loops, kotlin, append

I can't seem to find a right solution. Trying to add a list of array to another array. With my Python background it is easily done but not in Kotlin.

```
val extra = arrayOf(7,7,7)

fun containerArray() {

    val even = arrayOf(2, 4, 6)

    val odd = arrayOf(1, 3, 5)

    val arr1 = arrayOf(even, odd)

    val arr2 = arrayOf(*arr1, extra)



    print(arr2.contentDeepToString())

 }

 fun main() {

     for (i in 1..3) {

        containerArray() 

    }

 }
```

When executing above code I receive...

[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]][[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7,7,7]][...
What I want to achieve is this ....

```
[ [2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to get the following array:

```
[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]]
```

There is an overridden `+` (plus) operator for `Array`s in Kotlin, you can use it for adding arrays:

```
val arr2 = arr1 + extra
```

Resulting array `arr2` will contain all elements of the original array `arr1` and then all elements of the array `extra`.

ADDITIONALLY:

- You can add another array to `arr2`:

  ```
  val anotherArray = arrayOf(5, 5, 5)
  val arr3 = arr2 + anotherArray
  // result: [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7], [5, 5, 5]]
  ```
- If you want to use the same array `arr2` to store elements, you can create it with `var` modifier:

  ```
  var arr2 = arr1 + extra
  arr2 += arrayOf(5, 5, 5)
  ```
- There are different ways of what you are trying to achieve using a loop, for example:

  ```
  val even = arrayOf(2, 4, 6)
  val odd = arrayOf(1, 3, 5)
  val extra = arrayOf(7,7,7)

  var arr1 = arrayOf(even, odd)

  for (i in 1..3) {
      arr1 += extra
  }
  ```

`arr1` will contain next elements: `[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7]]`

Comment: What result do you want to get and are getting using `+` operator? This should work and the result array should be `[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]]`. I guess you wrongly described the result you want to get in your question then.

Comment: Sergey and @ cactustictacs absolutely right. The code example works but if I try to add and other array to arr2 using loop it just replacing the last element of the array. I have not tried the mutableList but I think it is the right approach in this case. So this is the result I looking for [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]] and after my loop add an extra element to the list like [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7], [5,5,5]] and so for on.

Comment: @PSoll I've added some additional information to my answer. I don't quite understand how you try to add elements in the loop, it would be nice to see some example (you can edit your question).

Comment: find a code here:  https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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

Comment: so you are calling `containerArray()` three times, and it prints the same result every time. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to add the new element (in this case the same element) to the arr2 container using loop. Instead of adding a new element the code only replace the last element in the array.

Comment: Could you please provide your code? I saw the link you've posted, but what elements are you adding and what element does it replace? I see you have arrays `[2, 4, 6]` and `[1, 3, 5]`, the third array `[7,7,7]` is added to the end and the result is: `[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]]`. The third array `[7,7,7]` doesn't replace anything.

Comment: This is sorted it out and also gave me a deeper understanding how array works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

To add a thing to an array of things, and produce a new array, use [`plusElement`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-element.html):

```
val arr2 = arr1.plusElement(extra)
```

This not only works for arrays, but also works for any `Iterable`s, i.e. `List`s, `Set`s etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do you get why you're getting that result? `arrayOf(items)` creates a new array wrapping those items, so `arrayOf(even, odd)` is an array that contains two arrays. Then you create another array, containing that array-of-arrays and another single array. You're nesting them as you go

Sweeper's answer is probably what you want, but there are a lot of ways to combine collections, flatten sequences etc. Like one thing you can do is use the `*`operator (the "spread operator") to "unpack" your arrays, so you get the items instead:

```
   // unpack arr1 from an array of arrays, into just those arrays
   // equivalent to arrayOf([2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], extra)
   val arr2 = arrayOf(*arr1, extra)

   print(arr2.contentDeepToString())
   >> [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]]
```

There's also `flatMap`, `flatten` etc - the best option depends on what you're doing!

---

Also when you say you want this:

```
[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]
```

that's just a bunch of values, not contained in anything, so we're assuming you want this:

```
[[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]]
```

where they're held in an array (or it could be a list). You could use the spread operator to unpack that into a bunch of values, but all you can do with that is pass it as a variable number of arguments to a function (which is what's happening in `arrayOf`)

Comment: Guys Thanks for your advise. Both the answers are added to my knowledge. #
cactustictacs to your question yes I want to achieve a nested array [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [7, 7, 7]] and than use and index to select a list of array. However in my scenario I'm using a for loop to add a new list to this array which does not work as I excpected.

Comment: @PSoll If you have your *container array* (the outer one) and the *item arrays* (the ``[2, 4, 6]`` etc), then you need to create your container, maybe starting with a couple of items included - ``arrayOf()`` or ``arrayOf(even, odd)``. Then just adding item arrays (using one of the plus methods in the other answers) is the easiest way to do it. ``arr1 += extra`` works!

Comment: @PSoll One thing to watch out for is that Kotlin encourages *immutable* collections, so there are lots of functions that don't change the original, they create a new copy with the changes, and return that. `plusElement` is one, so `arr1.plusElement(extra)` won't change `arr1`, it just produces a copy with the addition. That's necessary for arrays anyway - they're fixed length, if you want to "add" to one you need to create a new array and assign it to the variable. You'd generally use a `mutableList` instead - you can call `toTypedArray()` at the end if you really want an array for some reason