# Why does Kotlin change a list of type List<List<Int>> to List<Any> if a list is added with the "+" operator?

Tags: list, kotlin, types

Given the following two lists

```kotlin
val listA = listOf<List<Int>>()
val listB = listOf(1, 2, 3)
```

and the following operation

```kotlin
val listC = listA + listB
```

I am adding a list with the type `List<Int>` to a list with the type `List<List<Int>>`. However, my IDE is telling me that the type of the resulting list C is `List<Any>` and not, as I expected, `List<List<Int>>`. Could someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [list](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) of all `plus` operators in `kotlin.collections`, and you'll see that the one you are calling resolves to this one:

```
operator fun <T> Collection<T>.plus(
    elements: Iterable<T>
): List<T>
```

The compiler tries very hard to infer a type for `T`, so that the call is valid, and it finds `Any` as such a type. After all, a `List<List<Int>>` is a `Collection<Any>` and a `List<Int>` is also a `Iterable<Any>`.

Note that there is also:

```
operator fun <T> Collection<T>.plus(element: T): List<T>
```

However, overload resolution doesn't pick this one because the one that takes a `Iterable<T>` is considered "more specific". After all, it takes *specifically* an *`Iterable`*, rather than just any type (`T`), including `Iterable`. See also the [rationale section of the spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#rationale-1).

You should probably use [`plusElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405186/append-list-of-array-to-an-array-and-repeat-this-in-kotlin/70405260#70405260) instead.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation!